# output of the program with pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to c. During executing the program the first output shows that the result is z, then for the second one it shows 15, but fails to show the result when initialized to the long. Can anyone explain why?

```
main()
{
    char c,*cc;
    int i;
    long k;
    k=9999;
    c='z';
    i=15;
    cc=&c;
    printf("%c,%u",*cc,cc); 
    cc=&i;
    printf("\n%d,%u",*cc,cc);
    cc=&k;
    printf("\n%ld,%u",*cc,cc);
}
```

Comment: you should flush the last printf.

Comment: cc is of type pointer to char, so *cc is of type char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program declares `cc` to be a pointer to `char`. When you use `*cc` while it is pointing to an `int` or `long`, it takes only one `char` (a byte) from the place `cc` is pointing to.

The value you assign to `i`, 15, fits in one byte. And, in your C implementation, the bytes of an `int` are stored with the low-value bytes first, so, when `cc` points to the first byte of `i`, it points to the byte that contains 15. (Some C implementations store bytes in different orders; `cc` could point to the high-value byte instead of the low-value byte.)

The value you assign to `k`, 9999, does not fit in one byte. It requires two bytes, with 0xf (15) in the low byte and 0x27 (39) in the high byte (because 9999 = 39*256 + 15).

So, the value of `*cc` in the third `printf` is 15. However, there is still another problem. Since `cc` is a pointer to `char`, `*cc` is a `char`. In variable argument lists, which `printf` uses, `char` values are automatically promoted to `int`. However, the specifier `%ld` tells `printf` to expect a `long int`. You are passing the wrong type of argument.

When you pass the wrong type of argument, the behavior is not defined by the C specification. You should not expect this to work.

Additionally, `%u` is the wrong specifier to use to print pointers. The correct specifier is `%p`, and the pointers should be cast to `void *`. The third `printf` could work to show you the lowest byte of `k` if it were changed to:

```
printf("%d, %p", *cc, (void *) cc);
```

If you want to use `cc` to show the full value of `k`, then you must convert `cc` to a pointer to `long int` and use the correct specifier:

```
printf("%ld, %p", * (long int *) cc, (void *) cc);
```

Note that `cc` can be used in these ways only because pointer to `char` is treated specially by C. Converting between other pointer types, such as pointer to `int` and pointer to `float`, is not guaranteed to work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you are invoking unspecified behaviour.

A longer answer is:

Because, **on your system**, a pointer is as large as an `int` but smaller than a `long`.

First printf:

`*cc` is promoted to `int` (`char` and `short` are promoted to `int` when used as var-args).

`Printf` prints it as a `char` and displays `z`, just as expected.

Second printf:

`*cc` points to the first byte in `i`. It is promoted to `int` (`char` and `short` are promoted to `int` when used as var-args). Since it prints 15 (and not 0) we can tell that your system is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Third printf:

`*cc` points to the first byte in `k`. Since you are on a little-endian system, this evaluates to 15 (9999 = 15  + 39*2^8 ). It is promoted to `int` (`char` and `short` are promoted to `int` when used as var-args).

However, you provided the format specifier `%ld` which expects a long. My guess is, that on your system, a long is twice the size of an int, which means that it will print the pointer value combined with 15, which would result in some large number.

The second printf specifier will grab 4 bytes (assuming `int` is 32 bits) outside the current stack frame, which will either print a (maybe not so) random number or it may cause a segmentation fault.

Note:

I've made some assumptions regarding your system:

8 bit chars/bytes

32 bit int

32 bit pointers

64 bit long

Answer (score 1):

The assignments `cc = &i;` and `cc = &k;` are **probably** not allowed because they violate the following rule of (C99 6.5.16.1p1)[http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.5.16.1p1]:

> both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types,
>        and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the
>        right;

And in most cases `char` is neither compatible to `int` nor `long`.

Your compiler should warn you about that (make sure you have warnings enabled).

In the last `printf` you're also passing an argument of the wrong type, an `int` (because of default argument promotions) instead of a `long`, which `%ld` requires.

GCC and clang (and maybe others) would warn about that, too.